# ASP.NET Core webapp Azure deployment with reference to class library project

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core web app targeting net452 that I've been deploying to Azure from bitbucket.

I pulled all of my Azure Storage code out into a separate Class Library project in the solution -- 4.5.2 full framework -- because I want to share it with a WebJob.
This dll project is referenced by the Core webapp and works fine locally.  But now the Azure deployment fails because it can't find the nuget dependencies of the dll project.  Specifically, those dependencies are Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.3 and some of the Azure packages.

How can I resolve these dependencies on Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webjob project was in the same solution and bitbucket repo (the repo that was used for deployment) as the ASP.NET Core app.  *Azure was choking on the webjob packages.config.*  There was nothing wrong with the ASP.NET app. But Azure aborted because of the other project's error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try restoring all nuget packages. That action will remove all dll's of the existing packages and add them again.

```
nuget restore YourSolution.sln
```